# Why don't I have the Mortarboard Badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

This badge is earned by earning an excess of 200 (What are they?) points in one day. According to the timeline on my account, one day I got 212 points, 100 of that because I was trusted on other sites in the community. Is that why it didn't give me the achievement?

Note - It's not that important to me, I'm just curious.

Comment: [On this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67402#67402) I found this : "Reputation points earned for associating accounts do not count for the badge". Though it doesn't seem to be about the 'regular' badge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need 200 points from votes and accepts (+2 and +15 from accepts and +x from bounties count) to gain the `Mortarboard` badge. The +100 from associating a trusted account does not count.

See [this post on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45870/why-no-mortarboard-for-me), and [also this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101184/mortarboard-badge-not-awarded-for-200-reputation-in-a-day).

Moreover, the badges are only calculated every few hours, so even if you did get 200 points from voting, you may not see it for a few hours.

> Mortarboard bronze; awarded once
>   Earn more than 200 reputation in a single day
>   Reputation points earned for associating accounts do not count for the badge
>   Each "day" lasts from midnight UTC to immediately before midnight, UTC; days are not counted in local time
>   Exceeding the cap is defined as earning ≥200 reputation in one day from a combination of upvotes and accepts

Comment: Actually the accepted answers (both given and taken, 2 vs. 15) DO count

Comment: Interesting, I know the 15 pointers count, I could have sworn the +2 did as well.  I thought I had one where I was at 198 and that put me over

Comment: I never noticed that.

Comment: Hmm, it may have changed.... I'll do some more digging. come to think about it, +2 seem to count towards `Epic`, so it may count towards `Mortarboard` as well.

Comment: @bowlturner, found a comment [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88526/282772) from a diamond on meta stackexchange that suggests you're right. Updated answer.

Comment: So I'm not crazy!

Comment: I believe the +2 from *accepting* an answer doesn't count, because that's completely under your control, but the +15 from *having an answer accepted* does -- that, like votes, is under others' control, so you can't game it trivially.  (I had this happen once a year or so ago -- noticed I was at 198 for the day, accepted an answer, and didn't get Mortarboard.)

Answer (score 1):

The 100 points for the trusted site bonus doesn't count toward the daily 200 limit.